# Activate a Button Event with a KeyEvent

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I am very new to the concepts related to ActionListeners and KeyEvents.
I have the following code that should respond to a press of the down, up, and right arrows as follows:

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    switch(code){
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        oneRay[pick][0] = ("");
         if(i>=4){i=0; area.setText("");}
        caller();
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        area.append("\n"+oneRay[pick][1]);
         buton1.setEnabled(true);
         buton2.setEnabled(true);
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        if(i>=4){
             i=0;
             area.setText("");
         }
         caller();
    }}
```

Each keystroke corresponds to the action of a button, but whenever I try to activate the key, which occurs in the TextArea, the cursor simply moves up, down, left or right, and my code is not activated.
So, I am wondering why the key press may not be activated. Why? And also if it is possible to make a direct call to a button, and if that would work better than the code above.

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Comment: Also search this site for answers to similar questions (some by @AndrewThompson and some by me).

Comment: Please see my new question in a minute or so. Thank you for the suggestions but I am afraid, certainly by my fault, I am still stuck.

Comment: answered in new posting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18949213/131872